# Websql Insert Query

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html, web-sql

I am new websql.i cannot insert primary key in websql.

**Create Query**

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var sql =
         "CREATE TABLE vehicles ( "+
        "id integer primary key autoincrement,"+
        "vehicle_ref_no VARCHAR(255),"+
        "vehicle_plate_no VARCHAR(255),"+
        )";

        tx.executeSql(sql);

    });
```

**Insert Query**

```
 db.transaction(
        function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(
                "INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES (?, ?)",
                 [data.vehicle_ref_no, 
                 data.vehicle_plate_no, 

                 ],
                function (tx, result) {
                    console.log("Query Success");
                },
                function (tx, error) {
                    console.log("Query Error: " + error.message);
                }
            );
        },
        function (error) {

            console.log("Transaction Error: " + error.message);
        },
        function () {
            console.log("Transaction Success");
        }
    );
```

This code doesnot add the autoincrement value ,Any ideas?
Is there any good method for doing this other than what i do?

Comment: Why add primary key when it's already autoincremented????

Comment: I dont need to add primary key,the autoincrement field is not inserted by this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement is incorrect. You should either include names of columns other then `id`

```
INSERT INTO vehicles (vehicle_ref_no, vehicle_plate_no) VALUES (?, ?);
```

or pass NULL for `id`

```
INSERT INTO vehicles (id, vehicle_ref_no, vehicle_plate_no) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?);
```

or just

```
INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES (NULL, ?, ?);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/330b5/1)** demo

Comment: @peterm - Do you have to add the ***NULL*** keyword?  `(null, ?,?)` - My webSQL queries work fine just leaving it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public insertData(vehicle_details) {
    let insert_query = "INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES (?, ?)";
    this.db.executeSql(insert_query, [vehicle_details.vehicle_ref_no, vehicle_details.vehicle_plate_no]).then((data) => {
        console.log(' records inserted');
    }), (error) => {
        console.log('ERROR occurred in inserting records');

    }
}
```